# Dynamic Programming with Memoization not working properly

Tags: python, optimization, dynamic-programming, memoization

I have a rough solution to an optimization problem using dynamic programming. The aim is to get the shortest time to achieve the most satisfaction, with each item having individual time values, and a general optimal time for all the satisfactions.

```
def pp(list1, values, time_values, optimal_time, memo):
  list4 = []

  for i, j in zip(values, time_values):
    if (i,j,optimal_time) not in memo:
      memo[i,j,optimal_time] = (i * (optimal_time/j))
      list4.append(memo[i,j,optimal_time])

  zipped_lists = zip(list4, list1)
  sorted_pairs = sorted(zipped_lists)

  tuples = zip(*sorted_pairs)
  list4, list1= [list(tuple) for tuple in  tuples]
  return list(reversed(list1))

def getPP (list1, values, time_values, optimal_time):
  memo = {}
  return pp(list1, values, time_values, optimal_time, memo)
```

case 1: `print(getPP(["LOK", "MP", "HM", "AR", "SG", "VV"], [0.37, 0.87, 0.27, 0.87, 0, 0.56], [6, 1, 15, 3, 3, 3], 6))`

result: `['MP', 'AR', 'VV', 'LOK', 'HM', 'SG']`

The solution seems to work in certain cases.

When I try this, it omits the last item in the array, and my result is:

case 2: `print(getPP(["ARD", "AR", "GS", "LP", "MP", "ML", "SI", "VV"], [0.44, 0.67, 0.67, 0.5, 0.08, 0.44, 0.33, 0.87], [2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 5, 3, 3], 6))`

result: `['SI', 'AR', 'ARD', 'GS', 'ML', 'MP', 'LP']`

I'm not sure where the problem is.

Comment: It's note quite to me clear what your memoization (or your algorithm in general) is doing.  I see no duplication in `zip(values, time_values)`, so every pair is going to be added to your list4.   There's no recursion.  Could you add some comments about what your comment is supposed to be doing?

Comment: @FrankYellin It's a variation of the knapsack problem where I'm trying to sort those values and their individual time values in an order where maximum satisfaction is achieved in the shortest time. The memoization is to hold values that have already been calculated, so they are not repeated.